# Combining two or more columns into one

Tags: r

I have four columns:

| Year | I | I | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1951 | 4 | 6 | 7 |
| 1952 | 8 | 0 | 3 |
| 1953 | 3 | 2 | 9 |

how do I combine them into two like that?:

| Year | I |
| --- | --- |
| 1951 | 4 |
| 1951 | 6 |
| 1951 | 7 |
| 1952 | 8 |
| 1952 | 0 |
| 1952 | 3 |
| 1953 | 3 |
| 1953 | 2 |
| 1953 | 9 |

Comment: Could you please format your data in a better way? What are your columnames and what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure what your format is, but probably you want something like this by using `pivot_longer` to make your table from wide to long:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1951, 1952, 1953),
                 v1 = c(4,8,3),
                 v2 = c(6,0,2),
                 v3 = c(7,3,9))

library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "variable", values_to = "values")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
   Year variable values
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1  1951 v1            4
2  1951 v2            6
3  1951 v3            7
4  1952 v1            8
5  1952 v2            0
6  1952 v3            3
7  1953 v1            3
8  1953 v2            2
9  1953 v3            9
```